# HowTo parsed Stored Procs to get a list of tables and columns referenced in WHERE, GROUP BY, AND JOIN clauses

Tags: sql-server, statistics, system-tables

Is there a tool, script, utility that can parse `sys.sql_modules` and return a list of tables and columns referenced in the `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, and `JOIN` clauses of Stored Procedures?
Example:

```
CREATE PROC myProc  
BEGIN  
    SELECT a.col1, b.col2, count(a.col7) as MyCount  
    FROM dbo.FirstTable as a  
    JOIN dbo.SecondTable as b on (a.col1 = b.col1)  
    WHERE b.col5 = 'xxx'  
    GROUP BY a.col1,b.col2   
END
```

Return a list such as:

- `FirstTable.col1`
- `SecondTable.col2`
- `SecondTable.col5`
- `FirstTable.col1`
- `SecondTable.col2`

The goal is to use the result list to build some [`CREATE STATS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-statistics-transact-sql) commands based on the number of times a `table.col` pair is referenced.

Comment: Please tag your dbms.

Comment: And version please...

Comment: Do you have `AUTO CREATE STATS` turned off?

Answer (score 1):

[`sysdepends`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysdepends-transact-sql) & [`sys.sql_modules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-modules-transact-sql) have [some](https://thomaslarock.com/2010/11/why-you-cant-trust-sysdepends/) [known](https://sqlblog.org/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008) [limitations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/08/t-sql-tuesday-24-dude-wheres-the-rest-of-my-procedure)... and you probably don't want to perform string-parsing gymnastics if you want to rely on your results with a high level of confidence. Although neither of these options is really something I would recommend as an answer to your problem.

> The goal is to use the result list to build some `CREATE STATS` commands based on the number of times a table.col pair is referenced.

Perhaps you've got a highly targeted need to do exactly this, but my first reaction is that you might want to take a more holistic approach to your stats maintenance than reviewing the text inside stored procedures. You may have an heavy ad-hoc query load that doesn't ever touch a stored procedure. You may have 10 stored procs that reference *all the **things*** but are never called and 1 stored proc that touches less but is called *all the **time***. I recommend taking a step back and [browsing](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/importance-of-statistics-and-how-it-works-in-sql-server-part-1.html) [some](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/sql-server-statistics-basics/) [literature](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/07/not-just-create-statistics/) before taking the path you seem to be steering toward with this question.